# How to throw a ball to a specific point on plane?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to have catapult-like mechanism for shooting a ball at a specific point. For example, starting position of the ball is x=0, y=.5, z=0, and I want it to end up at x=10, y=0, z=20.  For now I'm using:

```
RigidBody.AddForce(new Vector3 (10, 15, 20) * thrust);
```

I'm averaging out 'y' element to between x and z, but thrust seems the most complex to calculate, I've tried estimating it by trial+error, but that can't the the correct solution.

Comment: You'll have to calculate it or guess and check, unless you want to modify physics.

Answer (score 5):

I created a solution by calculating initial velocity using the known locations of origin and target positions.  The variable named "transform" is the transform reference of the player's hand where the ball begins its journey through 3D space.  This script will cause a projectile to follow a path like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile above the plane toward the target.

For Example:

```
public class BallisticLauncherTest : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject ballGameObject;
    public Transform target;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        ThrowBallAtTargetLocation(target.position, 10f);    
    }

    // Throws ball at location with regards to gravity (assuming no obstacles in path) and initialVelocity (how hard to throw the ball)
    public void ThrowBallAtTargetLocation(Vector3 targetLocation, float initialVelocity)
    {
        Vector3 direction = (targetLocation - transform.position).normalized;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(targetLocation, transform.position);

        float firingElevationAngle = FiringElevationAngle(Physics.gravity.magnitude, distance, initialVelocity);
        Vector3 elevation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(firingElevationAngle, transform.right) * transform.up;
        float directionAngle = AngleBetweenAboutAxis(transform.forward, direction, transform.up);
        Vector3 velocity = Quaternion.AngleAxis(directionAngle, transform.up) * elevation * initialVelocity;

        // ballGameObject is object to be thrown
        ballGameObject.rigidbody.AddForce(velocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }

    // Helper method to find angle between two points (v1 & v2) with respect to axis n
    public static float AngleBetweenAboutAxis(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2, Vector3 n)
    {
        return Mathf.Atan2(
            Vector3.Dot(n, Vector3.Cross(v1, v2)),
            Vector3.Dot(v1, v2)) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    }

    // Helper method to find angle of elevation (ballistic trajectory) required to reach distance with initialVelocity
    // Does not take wind resistance into consideration.
    private float FiringElevationAngle(float gravity, float distance, float initialVelocity)
    {
        float angle = 0.5f * Mathf.Asin((gravity * distance) / (initialVelocity * initialVelocity)) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        return angle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't seem to work, and the method FiringElevationAngle is missing (I put in '45' for the value there). Could you test it to see if it works for you?

Comment: I added the missing FiringElevationAngle method, put all the code into a complete script, and tested to verify correct.